# Example for: $Cov(X,Y)=0$ but $Cov(h(X),Y)\neq0$ for some function $h(.)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

Can you help me find a simple example for this particular situation?

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that $Cov(X,Y)=0$ but $Cov(h(X),Y)\neq0$
for some function $h(.)$.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try: $X\sim\mathcal U\{-1,0,1\}, Y=X^2, h:s\mapsto s^2$

$\mathsf {Cov}(X,X^2)=0, \mathsf {Cov}(X^2,X^2)=1$

Comment: As @rjann says,  $\mathsf {Cov}(X^2,X^2)=\dfrac29$ rather than $1$

Answer (score 0):

I was just checking Graham's answer.It's a really nice simple example, but I found different values:

Assume $X$ takes value $-1$ with probability $1/3,$ $0$ with probability
$1/3$ and 1 with probability $1/3$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
E\left(X\right)=-1\times\frac{1}{3}+0\times\frac{1}{3}+1\times\frac{1}{3}=0,
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
E\left(X^{2}\right) & =\left(-1\right)^{2}\times\frac{1}{3}+0\times\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\\
 & =\frac{2}{3},
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
E\left(X^{3}\right) & =\left(-1\right)^{3}\times\frac{1}{3}+0\times\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\\
 & =0
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
E\left(X^{4}\right) & =\left(-1\right)^{4}\times\frac{1}{3}+0\times\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\\
 & =\frac{2}{3}.
\end{align*}
Let $Y=X^{2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
Cov(X,Y) & =Cov\left(X,X^{2}\right)\\
 & =E\left(X^{3}\right)-E\left(X\right)E\left(X^{2}\right)\\
 & =0
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
Cov(X^{2},Y) & =Cov\left(X^{2},X^{2}\right)\\
 & =E\left(X^{4}\right)-\left(E\left(X^{2}\right)\right)^{2}\\
 & =\frac{2}{3}-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2}\\
 & =\frac{2}{3}\left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right)\\
 & =\frac{2}{9}.
\end{align*}